# Change Workflow Manager 2013 credentials

Tags: credentials, service-account, workflow-manager

I need to change the service account running Workflow Manager 2013 and I am unable to find a procedure for doing this without dismantling the whole farm and starting again the process. I tried changing the Application Pool identity of the service, without results.

Can you please tell me if there's any way of doing this? And also, in the future when I change its password, would be enough to change it on the Application Pool identity or would I need to repeat the process?

Thanks.

Comment: I finally gave up and dismantled the farm for building it again. No real pain, but I find it weird that there's no other [easy-to-find] way.